# How to upload files to specific subdirectory

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a simple thing that uploads files using PHP.
My form:

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And PHP:

```
$id = '3';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $file = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
    $upload_dir = "uploads";
    if (file_exists($upload_dir."/".$file)) {
        die("File {$file} already exists in {$upload_dir} folder.");
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$file)) {
        $message = "File " . $file . " uploaded to " . $upload_dir;
        echo $message;
    } else {
        # Code with message about error.
    }
 }
```

Files successfully uploads only in `uploads` folder. In that `uploads` folder, I have few other folders: `1`, `2`, `3` and so on.

My question: How to move files in a specific subfolder after upload? (Subfolder name — from variable `id`.) Thanks!

Comment: You want to  `move` or `copy`???

Comment: `$upload_dir = "uploads/" . $id;`

Comment: This is what I was trying, if variable is `"uploads/" . $id` it doesnt upload. But I get `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

Comment: is that folder dynamically generated? check for the permissions of those folder.

Comment: Change $upload_dir = "uploads";  to $upload_dir = "uploads/".$id; and rest will be same.

Comment: Try this please it may works fine `$folder = $id; $dirPath = 'uploads/'.$folder;$result = mkdir($dirPath);` it will make the right directory path. now use `$dirPath` if `$result` having value one. if `$result` have value one it means directory created.

Comment: Problem was with the permissions of a folder (as @Toretto suggested), thanks for all comments on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Efficient way to do this:**

This method move file when it get uploaded.

```
    if (!empty($post_array['IconURI'])) {
        $IconURI_current_path = "./" . $post_array['IconURI'];
        if (file_exists($IconURI_current_path)) {
            // Desired folder structure
            $structure = './uploads/' . $primary_key . "/";
            // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
            // to mkdir() must be specified.
            if (is_dir($structure) || mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
                $dir = './uploads/' . $primary_key . "/" . $post_array['IconURI'];
                chmod("$IconURI_current_path", 0777);
                if (copy("$IconURI_current_path", "$dir")) {
                    @unlink("$IconURI_current_path");
                    //rename IconURI from [ 9723d-632ac-e325b-db1b8-icon.jpg ] 
                    $IconURI = "uploads/" . $primary_key . "/" . $post_array['IconURI'];
                }
            } else {
                die('Failed to create folders...');
            }
        } else {
            echo "Banner file does not exist";
        }
    }
```

the script also handle file permissions. some time due to directory or files permission file couldn't moved.

Can be used as callback function like in Grocery CRUD or other third party Plugins. i.e these plugins uploads files to their default directory and you some time need to move file to other specific directory.